# Combining two queries - how?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following queries:

Query 1:

```
Select * from T10,T11,T12,T13,T14 
where T10.C0 = T11.C0 and T11.C1 = T12.C0 
and T12.C1 = T13.C0 and T13.C1 = T14.C0;
```

Query 2:

```
Select * from T20,T21,T22,T23,T24 
where T20.C0 = T21.C0 and T21.C1 = T22.C0 
and T22.C1 = T23.C0 and T23.C1 = T24.C0;
```

How can I combine these 2 queries to show all the values of these tables? I want the join to be on `T10.C1 = T20.C1`.

When trying `union` I get a warning about not having the same number of columns, which is true, these tables are not the same

---

**union**

```
Select * from 
"ProductConfig","Board","PcbBuild","Model","TcssCalib" 
where "Model"."idModel" = "PcbBuild"."Model" and "Board"."PcbBuild" = "PcbBuild"."idPcbBuild" 
and "Board"."idBoard" = "TcssCalib"."Board" and "ProductConfig"."TcssCalib" = "TcssCalib"."idTcssCalib"

union

Select * from"ProductBuild","TxResultsLink","TxResults","DspValues" where "ProductBuild"."idProductBuild"
 = "TxResultsLink"."ProductBuild" and "TxResults"."idTxResults" = "TxResultsLink"."TxResults" 
and "TxResults"."DspValues" = "DspValues"."idDspValues";
```

here i want ProductBuild.Productconfig joined with ProductConfig.idProductConfig

gives an error:

[Err] ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns

---

When I try `inner join` I get a syntax error at or near `inner`

Is there a way to join these 2 queries together?

Comment: A JOIN is the way to go. Post your JOIN query code so we can help debugging it. Also, I hope these are obfuscated columns names.

Comment: yes these are 'made up' table and column names (otherwize they would become unreadable i think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
Select * from T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T20,T21,T22,T23,T24
where T10.C0 = T11.C0 and T11.C1 = T12.C0 
and T12.C1 = T13.C0 and T13.C1 = T14.C0
and T10.C1 = T20.C1 and T20.C0 = T21.C0 and T21.C1 = T22.C0 
and T22.C1 = T23.C0 and T23.C1 = T24.C0;
```

---

and another, more readable way to put it, is like this:

```
select * from T10
  inner join T11 on T10.C0 = T11.C0
  inner join T12 on T11.C1 = T12.C0 
  inner join T13 on T12.C1 = T13.C0 
  inner join T14 on T13.C1 = T14.C0
  inner join T20 on T10.C1 = T20.C1
  inner join T21 on T20.C0 = T21.C0
  inner join T22 on T21.C1 = T22.C0 
  inner join T23 on T22.C1 = T23.C0
  inner join T24 on T23.C1 = T24.C0;
```

---

For `UNION` to result, the number of columns in the tables needs to be the same and from the same/convertable datatype.

```
Select * from T10,T11,T12,T13,T14 
where T10.C0 = T11.C0 and T11.C1 = T12.C0 
and T12.C1 = T13.C0 and T13.C1 = T14.C0

UNION

Select * from T20,T21,T22,T23,T24 
where T20.C0 = T21.C0 and T21.C1 = T22.C0 
and T22.C1 = T23.C0 and T23.C1 = T24.C0;
```

---

```
Select * from 
"ProductConfig","Board","PcbBuild","Model","TcssCalib","ProductBuild","TxResultsLink","TxResults","DspValues"
where "Model"."idModel" = "PcbBuild"."Model" and "Board"."PcbBuild" = "PcbBuild"."idPcbBuild" 
and "Board"."idBoard" = "TcssCalib"."Board" and "ProductConfig"."TcssCalib" = "TcssCalib"."idTcssCalib" and "ProductBuild"."idProductBuild"
 = "TxResultsLink"."ProductBuild" and "TxResults"."idTxResults" = "TxResultsLink"."TxResults" 
and "TxResults"."DspValues" = "DspValues"."idDspValues"
and "ProductBuild"."ProductConfig" = "ProductConfig"."idProductConfig";
```

Comment: this is what i want, but i got my 2 query's made up already (build by C#) and i was wondering if i could easily join these query's

Comment: The proper way to do it is using one the queries that I specified.

Comment: i tried your union approach but that gives an error in my case (see my edited question)

Comment: @Moonlight How do you connect one query with the other?

Comment: ProductBuild.ProductConfig joined with ProductConfig.idProductConfig

Comment: so in short, i cant just join 2 querys(select table where foo) together! i need to rebuild them to create a new query which gives the results

Comment: yes you can join them, but this is better. And you should use inner join instead of nested joins.